# postgres - single record with one to many join tables

Tags: postgresql, select

I have two tables a and b. Where main table is 'a' where I want to select from and table 'b' is for filtering.
Below is sample table with some data.

```
create table a (
   id varchar primary key,
   name varchar,
   p varchar[]
);

insert into a (id, name, p) values 
 ('1', 'v1', array['p1']),
 ('2', 'v2', array['p1','p2']),
 ('3', 'v3', array['p2','p3']);


create table b (
   p varchar,
   x varchar
);

insert into b(p, x) values
   ('p1', 'x1'),
   ('p2', 'x2'),
   ('p3', 'x1'),
   ('p3', 'x3'),
   ('p1', 'x2');
```

I want only one row from table a based on join on column p and filter on x. I tried few options, it works when I have one to one record in a and b but when I have one to many then I get multiple records.

```
select a.* from a,b where b.p=any(a.p) and b.x='x2';
```

Output I get is:

```
id  name   p  
-----------------
1   v1     p1  
2   v2     p1,p2  
2   v2     p1,p2  
3   v3     p2,p3
```

What I want is

```
id  name   p  
-----------------
1   v1     p1   
2   v2     p1,p2  
3   v3     p2,p3
```

Also I am expecting **table 'a' to have millions of rows and 'b' will have only few**, so query has to be perform effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only want columns from table `a` use an `exists` condition rather than a join:

```
select a.* 
from a
where exists (select *
              from b
              where b.p = any(a.p) 
                and b.x='x2');
```

That will however be quite hard to optimize.

Another option - if not too many rows match the join criteria - is to apply a distinct on the result of the join.

In that case a GIN index on the array column can be used:

```
create index on a using gin (p);

select distinct a.* 
from a
  join b on a.p @> array[b.p]
where b.x= 'x2';
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. This works functionally, I need to check about performance. On second query, we are expecting around close to 1 million rows from 'a' table on that join. I will check this and update this thread.

Comment: If you get back that many rows, I doubt you can improve that substantially with that data model.  A proper one-to-many relationship will be a lot easier to index

Comment: Yes we tried like having table (aid, p) instead of array of p and then (p, x) but It was getting into similar issue. Are you suggesting similar data model for one to many or its different?

Comment: Since functionally this is working and not bad with performance with either, I am accepting this answer. Thanks a_horse_with_no_name